# How do I access an object in a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I've inherited some really ugly code. A `print_r` on a variable called `$this->pizza_topping_list` returns the following (I've stripped out all but two of the "sub-objects", but there are actually about 70.

```
error_log(print_r($this->pizza_topping_list, 1));

[18-Feb-2014 11:46:52] MenuPizzaToppingList Object
(
    [b_index:MenuPizzaToppingList:private] => Array
        (
            [@] => 36
            [A] => 21
            [B] => 4
        )

    [menu_pizza_toppings:MenuPizzaToppingList:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => MenuPizzaTopping Object
                (
                    [code:MenuPizzaTopping:private] => P
                    [short_description:MenuPizzaTopping:private] => Pepperoni
                    [category:MenuPizzaTopping:private] => M
                )

            [1] => MenuPizzaTopping Object
                (
                    [code:MenuPizzaTopping:private] => B
                    [short_description:MenuPizzaTopping:private] => Barbecue
                    [category:MenuPizzaTopping:private] => S
                )

        )

)
```

If I were to loop through this (i.e. `foreach($pizzatoppings as $topping)`, how would I access the `category` property of the `menu_pizza_toppings` objects? I need a way to filter out all items with a category of S.

I've tried the following:

```
foreach($this->pizza_topping_list['menu_pizza_toppings'] as $tmpTopping) {
   error_log("category: " . $tmpTopping['category']);
}
```

But get a fatal error "cannot use object of type MenuPizzaToppingList as array".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a getter method to the `MenuPizzaTopping` class.

So for example you can get the value this way:

```
foreach($this->pizza_topping_list['menu_pizza_toppings'] as $tmpTopping) {
    error_log("category: " . $tmpTopping->getCategory());
}
```

Comment: I just tried that a few minutes ago, but I still get the same error. The error is referencing the `MenuPizzaToppingList` class, not the `MenuPizzaTopping` class.

Comment: You're trying to use an object as an array (as the error msg says) so instead of this `foreach($this->pizza_topping_list['menu_pizza_toppings'] as $tmpTopping) {` try something like this: `foreach($this->pizza_topping_list->menu_pizza_toppings as $tmpTopping) {`. But this property is also private, so you may have to modify the `MenuPizzaToppingList` first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call $tmpTopping->category or possibly $tmpTopping->getCategory(), depending on the encapsulation. Do you have the code for the class of the object?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have the getter to the menu_pizza_toppings member...

try this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php
it is about doing a reflection in a class and iterating over members, even if they are private.

complement it with: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php (accessing the property properties xD, and then the value using getValue()).

```
$prop = new ReflectionClass($your_MPTL_instance)->getProperty('menu_pizza_toppings');  
$prop->setAccessible(true);  
$value = $prop->getValue($your_MPTL_instance);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$tmpTopping` is an instance object `MenuPizzaTopping`, but `category` is a private member that is not accessible outside the instance